# How to resize all of the objects on my wpf form when window is set to maximize

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new with WPF forms so this may be easy, but...

I created a new wpf form and added 12 images to it. I set the window to maximize which I believe will fit it to any monitor it is viewed on, right? How do I get my objects shift around so it looks generally the same when in the maximized mode?

The first image is what it looks like in the designer, the second is what it looks like when the program is running.

[image: In the designer:]
[image: When running:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you want to stretch your entire UI. Then ViewBox control is extremely helpful:

```
<Window ...>
  <ViewBox>
      <Grid Height="800" Width="600">
          <!-- Everything inside viewbox will be stretched as you resize window
               Place you UI assuming you have virtual resolution 800x600 -->
      </Grid>
  </ViewBox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use WrapPanel to lay out your images:

```
<WrapPanel>
<Image x:Name="b1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="blackCircle.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Image x:Name="b2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="blackCircle.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="b4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="blackCircle.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="b3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="blackCircle.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Image x:Name="b5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="blackCircle.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Image x:Name="b6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="blackCircle.png"/>        
    <Image x:Name="y1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Source="yellowCircle.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="y2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Source="yellowCircle.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Image x:Name="y3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="51" Source="yellowCircle.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="y4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="yellowCircle.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Image x:Name="y5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="yellowCircle.png"/>
    <Image x:Name="y6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="yellowCircle.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

`WrapPanel` automatically wraps to new lines if there is not not enough space.

**Update:**

I've made a test for 5 images, but you can do for 12 images. To do 12 images you should add 12 columns. Let me show an example:

```
<Window x:Class="SOWpfApplication.MainWindow"
       <!--The code omitted for the brevity-->
        >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="/Images/Back.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="/Images/Forward.jpg" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="/Images/Back.jpg" Grid.Column="2" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="/Images/Back.jpg" Grid.Column="3" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <Image Source="/Images/Forward.jpg" Grid.Column="4" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Grid>

        <TextBlock Text="Time is up!" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"/>        
        <Button Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" Width="150" Content="Close" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem I am having. I will see if I can add screenshots to my question.

Comment: I made edits to my original question. I fixed the second part.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is in the editor of the part that you want to expand, select anchor for top and right, as this usually is enough stretching for my purpose. However, play around with the anchor, as that is what will get you the scaling you are looking for. In your case, you might want to anchor all four sides of everything you want scaled.

***Edit***

Alternately, you can also select stretch for both vertical and horizontal alignment, which will cause the stretching as well. Note, just make sure you use margins to position the images where you want.

Comment: If you want to scale everything  (look larger to fit the screen), you may use a `ViewBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Height & width property as "Auto" , This will automatically resize all the elements on your form.

regards,
Vishal